# Python: Extracting data from nested dictionary with single keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of about 300 dictionary each of which has elements as follows:

```
myDictList[0]
{1: {1: {'XX':5, 'YY':7}}}

myDictList[1]
{11: {25: {'XX':15, 'YY':73}}}
```

I want to instead generate

```
myDictList[0] = {}
myDictList[1] = {}
myDictList[0][1][1] = {'XX':5, 'YY':7}
myDictList[1][11][25] = {'XX':15, 'YY':73}
```

I am trying a `for loop` right now. Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Edit:

myDictList is `list` and others are `dictionary` as follows:

```
myDictList[0] = {}
myDictList[0][1] = {}
myDictList[0][1][1] = {}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what it is you are trying to do, but a for-loop *is* pythonic.

Comment: What is the value of, say, `myDictList[0][0]`?

Comment: I agree, is there smarter way to do the above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing to do:

```
myDictList[0] == {1: {1: {'XX':5, 'YY':7}}}
```

Is the same as:

```
myDictList[0][1][1] == {'XX':5, 'YY':7}
```